# What is the #1 Popular Target medal for?

Tags: splatoon-3

What is the #1 Populat Target medal given for? it's not related to deaths as I managed to get it in a round where I never died, and it's not most damage taken since there's a separate [#1 Damage Taker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG32U.jpg) medal.

[image: #1 Popular Target]

Comment: I think it just means you were shot at the most on your team, everyone was targeting you

Comment: I've learned there's a separate [#1 Damage Taker](https://i.imgur.com/thcR8bb.jpg) medal, so being targeted is different than total damage taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to analysis done by [@LeanYoshi on Twitter](https://twitter.com/LeanYoshi/status/1581407920574857217), the "#1 Popular Target" medal is awarded to the player who is most often seen within the field of view of the enemy team members' crosshairs (regardless of distance).

On [their website](https://leanny.github.io/splat3/medals.html#), they have a list of all the medals and the criteria for earning them.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to figure it out for a couple weeks now, I’m pretty sure the #1 Popular Target medal is given to the player with the least amount of deaths, making them a “popular target to aim for,” kinda like in Free for All Smash Bros where everyone gangs up on the player with the most stocks.